# Java - Shorter session timeout for low "used time"

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I have a Java web application deployed to Tomcat. In my web.xml I specify the maximum idle timeout. However, we monitor uptime of this web application by pinging a number of pages and checking for a 200 response. Each ping initiates a session and with multiple pings every few seconds, we rack up a large number of sessions.

These sessions eventually timeout, but I'd love to remove them sooner.

In the Tomcat "Sessions Administration" page, I can easily tell which fall into this category. Their "Inactive Time" is greater than a few seconds, but their "Used Time" is 00:00. This says, they made a single request and have not returned to make another.

**Question**

Is there any way to timeout these inactive single requests without affecting users?

**Additional Info**

- Our session timeout is currently set pretty high, over an hour. The customer knows best =)
- Our web framework is heavily AJAX based, so having no followup requests is pretty unlikely for a real user.
- To the best of our knowledge, we have no control over session handling from the monitoring tool's side.

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head:

1. Use the same session - make an initial request and save the session id, and then make every subsequent request using that id.
2. Send a special header when pinging (for example `X-Invalidate-Session`). Implement a filter that will invalidate the session immediately after the request.
3. Measure performance with and without the "ping" requests. If there's no significant difference, stop worrying about it.

I'd say that this question is too broad for SO, since there are definitely more possibilities of solving this.